# How to make a Custom View occupy completely in a perspective in an RCP application

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I’ve created an RCP application with a view as a template 
Initially After creating project my perspective class looks like this

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout;

public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.setFixed(true);

    }

}
```

I’ve created a new view and added to org.eclipse.ui.views extension named ErrorView and generated respective class of that view.
I made a small change to perspective class

```
public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {
     private URL u;
        private HttpURLConnection huc;
    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
        try{
            u= new URL("https://google.com/");
            huc = ( HttpURLConnection )u.openConnection ();
            huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
            huc.connect();
        if(huc.getResponseCode()==200){
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.setFixed(true);
         }
         else{
             layout.addStandaloneView(View1.ID, true, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, layout.getEditorArea());
             layout.getViewLayout(View1.ID).setCloseable(false);
             layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
         }
        }
         catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                layout.addStandaloneView(View1.ID, true, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, layout.getEditorArea());
                layout.getViewLayout(View1.ID).setCloseable(false);
                layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
            }
    }
}
```

Definitely else/catch block gets executed

[image: output]

How can I make the ErrorView occupy entire perspective without showing Base view or simply hide the base(default view) Completely.

Comment: The `IPerspectiveFactory` class is only executed once, to define the layout the first time the perspective is opened.  It is not run after that, as the layout is already known.  What behaviour is it that you want?  Is it a startup behaviour (like you restart and an editor is open but google won't give you information)?

Comment: @Paul Webster  
to be more precise i want to show erroview alone completely that fits in the perspective instead of loading the default view(right side part in the image above). Yes it's a kinda startup behavior before a view is shown i want to show any view other than the default view(created by using eclipse rcp **View template** ).Hope you understood paul,i'm ready to elaborate the question

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in the IPerspectiveFactory, as an instance of that class is only executed once, to define the layout the first time the perspective is optened.  After that the layout is known and the instance is not re-run.

But at runtime if you can determine that you want your ErrorView to dominate your perspective, you can use `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.setPartState(IWorkbenchPartReference, int)` to MAXIMIZE that part.

EDIT: API info

See [Plugging into the Workbench](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench.htm) for more information.  You can get the IWorkbenchPage from your view or editor site if you are a part, or from the IWorkbenchWindow which you can get from the ExecutionEvent if you are in a command handler.  You can also get the active IWorkbenchWindow from the statics on `org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI` although this is the least preferred method.

Comment: seems like apt but i could not implement IWorkbenchPage interface, in which class should i implement this interface and little new to the usage of this setPartState method

Answer (score 1):

The view is either defined in your Perspective class or in the plugin.xml. Open your `MANIFEST.MF`, switch to the `Extensions` tab and select `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`. Here are the views of a perspective defined by configuration. Remove your "default view". Then you also could delete the view in the `org.eclipse.ui.views` node